# AsynTask inside service: dealing with Screen Orientation

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-service

I have a trouble with screen orientation when using AsyncTask even it's inside Service.
My service look like:

```
public class RequestService extends Service {   
private MyBinder binder;        

public RequestService(){
    binder = new MyBinder(RequestService.this);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return binder;
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder{
    private final RequestService service;       
    public MyBinder(RequestService service){
        this.service = service;
    }       

    public RequestService getService(){
        return this.service;
    }
}   
public <T> void sendRequest(Request<T> task, INotifyRequest<T> notify){
    // Call excute the asynctask and notify result in onPostExcute
    new TaskExecutor<T>(task, notify).execute();
}
}
```

Update: I use my Service like this:

```
 // start the service
 final Intent intent = new Intent(context, serviceClass);
 context.startService(intent);

 // then bound the service:
 final Intent intentService = new Intent(context, serviceClass);
 // Implement the Service Connection
 serviceConnection = new RequestServiceConnection();
 context.getApplicationContext().bindService(intentService, serviceConnection,
                    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

When orientation changing, the service is unbound then re-bound, the `AsyncTask` doesn't notify to update UI. *I wonder why it could happen even `AsyncTask` inside the `Service`?*
I have read [this post](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/dealing-with-asynctask-and-screen-orientation/), but I don't want to lock the screen orientation or something like that. I prefer the `Service` than `IntentService` as `Service` 's flexible, I can use it with the Binder to get Service instance. 
So, the question is, is there any way to do thread safe inside the `Service` rather than `AsyncTask`?

Comment: What if you started the Service explicitly with `Context.startService()`?

Comment: @Karakuri I use the bindService to get the service instance through binder in Service Connection

Comment: @Karakuri Sorry, I just re-check my code. It's use both case: startService and bindService, and I start service in activity onStart() therefore service can alive when orientation changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a bound service keep in mind, that the Service will be destroyed if no Activity is bound. I don't know if you unbind in onPause(), but this would destroy your Service at an orientation change.

Because of this you will loose the Service and the reference to the AsyncTask. Furthermore there is no onRetainInstanceState() available for a Service, to save the AsyncTask and grab it again.

Think about an IntentService in this case it would be the proper way. Or if you wanna keep the Service use startService(), to keep it alive while no Activity is bound. Then you can still bind and unbind from the service the way you want.

The next point is to keep a reference of the AsyncTask. Because you have to set your callback again if the Activity was destroyed. Because the callback reference will still be set to the old Activity.

Hope this helps.

Edit:

Well if you read that maybe you consider using a IntentService or something..

Keep a instance of the AsyncTask in the Service and define a setter in your Task for your callback. 
If your Activity binds to the service after the orientation change check, whether the AsyncTask is running. If it's running update the callback. You can use your Binder for that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing to post the startService in my code. I use both startService and bindService and I start service in onStart() of activity, therefore I can keep the service alive. Could you give me  the detail "keep reference of AsyncTask"? I have to keep it as variable in service? Then what will I do when the activity recreate?